# How Do Stargates in the Milky Way Galaxy, the Pegasus Galaxy, and on the Destiny Differ?

Tags: stargate

The stargates in the Pegasus galaxy have different glyphs on them than the ones in the Milky Way galaxy (which are mainly cosmetic) and there are fewer glyphs on the Pegasus galaxy gates.  I don't remember the glyphs on the gates on board the *Destiny*, but I do remember that they seem to have a much more limited range.  They can't connect to gates all over the local galaxy, like Milky Way gates seem to be able to do.

Are there other differences?  What are the differences between the gates on the *Destiny*, in the Milky Way, and in the Pegasus galaxy?

Comment: The glyphs on Destiny's gates are a plain numerical sequence, made with dots and dashes.  And yeah, they're limited to a small section of the galaxies seen on-screen (which maaay just mean they're enormous galaxies..?)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Destiny Gate System

- **Age**: Oldest
- **Network Span**: Intergalactic (unknown size)
- **Number of symbols on gate ring**: 36
- [**Glyph design**](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Glyph): Abstract; do not represent any constellations (since it is a dynamically evolving network spanning multiple galaxies)
- **Address size**: 7 for pan-galactic, 9 for intergalactic
- **Range**: Low; requires proximity for dialing (cannot dial all gates within a galaxy) unless dialing intergalactic
- **Point of origin (POO)**: No unique POO per gate; all gates are of an identical design

### Milky Way Gate System

- **Age**: Second oldest
- **Span**: Pan-galactic + intergalactic
- **Symbols**: 39
- **Glyph design**: Constellations
- **Address size**: 7 for pan-galactic, 8 for intergalactic (when dialing fixed destinations), 9 for dialing moving destinations (e.g *Destiny*)
- **Point of origin**: Unique to each gate
- **Range**: Pan-galactic under normal operation
- **Other features**: Manual dial capability (gate ring can be rotated by hand or mechanically)

### Pegasus Gate System

- **Age**: Latest
- **Span**: Pan-galactic + intergalactic
- **Symbols**: 36
- **Glyph design**: Pegasus constellations
- **Address size**: Same as milky way system
- **Point of origin**: ??
- **Range**: Pan-galactic under normal operation
- **Other features**:

  - No moving parts
  - No manual dialing
  - Restricted intergalactic dialing (requires special crystal only present in Atlantis DHD)
  - Backward compatibility with older gate systems
  - Overrides any older gates in the same location

Comment: I forgot one more thing. The Destiny gate seems to retain its address despite moving through space. Whereas other gates' addresses need to be recalculated when they move.

Comment: Source(s)? Please add to the answer

Comment: Moving isn't the key to a 9 point dialing. I think it is extreme distance, but I'm not sure...

Comment: Don't forget Destiny's lack of DHDs

Comment: @DVK Everything is from SG-1, SGA and SGU episodes I've watched. The number of symbols in the Destiny system is the only think I had too look up from http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Glyph. I could reference individual episodes,  but it's going to take a lot of time.

Comment: @HNL I thought the Destiny's address changed as it moved, the hand held dialing devices access the same subspace network that destiny uses to communicate with the gates (most likely using the nearest gate) so some random address appears on the dhd with destiny written next to it.

Comment: @Arcath In episode S01E15 - Lost, Eli was able to identify Destiny on the remote dialer, recognizing the address. Since the remote only shows the gates in range and is able to identify when Destiny is in range as well, it's likely Destiny broadcasts it's position, maybe in similar fashion Milky Way stargates broadcast updates to adjust for stellar drift. That way, even if location changes, the address can stay the same.